# In Omnet++, where can find different values of parameters?

Tags: omnet++

If anyone know where can see different values (settings) of a parameter? For example, if we need to change a default value, which other options do we have to set.

Thanks

Comment: The parameters, and their default values, are defined in `.ned` files.

Comment: thanks @Attila for your answer. But I am exactly looking for other values of a parameter rather than its default values. For example, I know that for "*.hostR*.mobility.typename = "LinearMobility"", there are another type-names such as Circular or Square. However, I wonder is there any fast and standard way to find these other values? for example some drop-down menu, some short keys, etc.

Answer (score 3):

The default settings are located in the according `.ned` file of your module. If you have a setup for your simulation you're usually changing your parameters in the `omnetpp.ini` file.

The TicToc tutorial gives you all information according to this, especially [TicToc 7](https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/tictoc/part7/) might be useful for you.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I find the other values of a parameter? for example something like a drop-down menu, etc.

Comment: In the omnetpp.ini file? I suggest to use the "Source" tab and not the "Form". In the Source tab you can just add your parameter as described in the tutorial.